# Custom Tensorflow Layer From Two Input Sources

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to build a custom TensorFlow layer from two "input sources" that should do this

exp(source A) + cos(source B)

However, I have no idea how to even set-up writing such a *custom layer*.

**Note:** I'm really looking to learn/understand how this works so a workaround would be sub-optimal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a possibility

```
class custom_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self):
        super(custom_layer, self).__init__()
        pass

    def call(self, inputs):

        input1, input2 = inputs
        return tf.exp(input1) + tf.cos(input2)

inp1 = Input((10,))
inp2 = Input((10,))
x = custom_layer()([inp1,inp2])
x = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model([inp1,inp2],x)
model.compile('adam','mse')
model.summary()

X1 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,10))
X2 = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,10))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, 100)

model.fit([X1,X2],y, epochs=3)
```